# Use prop_test over multiple summary stats

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this:

```
education = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0,0) 
college = c(1, 0, 1, 1,1,0) 
income = c(55, 55, 12, 15, 90, 230) 
age = c(1, 0, 1, 1,1,0) 
female = c(1, 1, 1, 0,1,0) 
group = c(0, 0, 0, 1,1,1)
df = data.frame(group, female, age, education, income, college)
```

What i want to do is to get a table with the mean for each variable (income, college, education, female, age) for group=1 and for group=0. Then i want to get the p-value for the prop test that means are equal for group 1 and group0 for each income, age, female..[image: Example final output here]

What i thought i could do was :

```
balance_stats <- df %>%
  group_by(as.factor(group)) %>% 
  summarise(across(c("income", "education",  "age", "female",~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))

total_stats <- df %>% 
  summarise(across(c("income", "education",  "age", "female",~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

And then take out `balance_stats$group0` and `balance_stats$group1` and do `prop.test( x=c(balance_stats$group0mbalance_stats$group1), n=total_stats)`

But it does not work as expected.. any help please

Comment: The last line should read `summarise(across(c("income", "education",  "age", "female"),~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))`. Also, I don't understand - `balance_stats` and `total_stats` are exactly the same.

Comment: Hey Phil, just edited it, baance stats was mean to have group aggreagation and then i just take group0 and group1 and compare it with total stats

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  arrange(group) %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = c("female", "age", "education", "income", "college"),
                   .fns = list(mean0 = ~mean(.x[seq(1, sum(group == 0))]),
                               mean1 = ~mean(.x[seq(1 + sum(group == 0), n())]),
                               p = ~t.test(x = .x[seq(1, sum(group == 0))],
                                           y = .x[seq(1 + sum(group == 0), n())])[["p.value"]]),
                   .names = "{col}_{fn}")) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = c("variable", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)")

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  variable   mean0   mean1     p
  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 female     1       0.333 0.184
2 age        0.667   0.667 1    
3 education  0.667   0     0.184
4 income    40.7   112.    0.377
5 college    0.667   0.667 1
```

p.s. You mentioned `prop.test` in your question, but the accompanying example states `t.test`. I'm going with the latter here, since one of the variables in your dataset (income) isn't binary, so I'm not sure how to interpret `prop.test`'s proportions (probability of success) in this context. You can change the code accordingly if your real use case is different.